# Why is IndexOf not matching the entire substring?

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexof

I am trying to make a text-based game, and I need to use Javascript and/or jQuery to search the user input from a textarea element for certain substrings in order to trigger unique responses.

I have tried using PHP to submit the input as form data, but for the purposes of my code it is simpler to use JS/jQuery. I am currently using the indexOf() method.

```js
var substr = "test substr";
function test() {
  var textareaVal = $("#wiyetxt").val();
  if (substr.indexOf(textareaVal) !== -1) {
    alert("Found");
  }
  else {
    alert("Nope");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="wiyetxt"></textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="test();" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Clear">
```

I expected my function to alert "Found" when my input contains the string "test substr", however it alerts "Found" if any of the letters in the substring are present in order. For example, "t", "es", and "substr" all alert "Found" as well as the exact string. However, if I add anything to the string it alerts "Nope", for example, "test substr test substr" returns "Nope". Why might this be happening?

Comment: My guess is you're confusing the two strings and you're looking for `textareaVal.indexOf(substr)`. It's `haystack.indexOf(needle)`, not the other way around.

Comment: Yep that was the problem. Thanks for the fast response!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're finding substrings of your variable instead of finding substrings of your input string.

You'll want to flip the argument of the indexOf like this:

```
if (textareaVal.indexOf(substr) !== -1) {
```

Comment: Yep that was the problem. Thanks for the fast response! I'll accept your answer as soon as Stack will let me.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I've misunderstood, I think the issue is that you're trying to check whether `substr` contains the value that is in the text area but you should actually be checking the *opposite*. I.e. Does the value in the text area contain the substring?

Try to flip the expression from:

```js
substr.indexOf(textareaVal)
```

to

```js
textareaVal.indexOf(substr)
```

Answer (score -1):

ES6 way:

```
if (textareaVal.includes(substr)) {
    alert("Found");
} else {
    alert("Nope");
}
```

Comment: Code only answers don't always help the OP or future readers of your answer, try to specify why you choose for `include` vs `indexOf` as the OP asked for